# How to read the downloaded file in android?

Tags: android

I configure my email in the Android simulator(Default Email configuration in android aimulator 2.1) .And I download the attachment from my mail. I need to read that file in my application .Is there any possibility to read the file in my application. I am new to android. Can anyone help me to solve this ??? Thanks in advance?

Note in the Eclipse android file explore it show the data in data/data/com.email.attachmentprovidr/databases/_att.1/**1**  I export that object 1 to my computer it has the actual data

Comment: Do you know the location of the file each time? if you do, then you can use the standard Java File Reading Classes (eg. `FileInputStream`)

Comment: when i try to read that its not supports to read.

Comment: What do you mean by "not supports to read" what is the error.